# ConcurrentModificationException - Memcached set & get from multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, memcached

I am getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when I am using Memcached for setting & getting value from multiple thread concurrently.

**Exception stack trace :**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:934)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:932)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1098)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at com.danga.MemCached.MemCachedClient.set(MemCachedClient.java:763)
    at com.danga.MemCached.MemCachedClient.set(MemCachedClient.java:542)
    at com.cacheengine.MemcachedThreadUtil.addToMemCache(MemcachedThreadUtil.java:129)
    at com.cacheengine.MemcachedThreadUtil.memcacheDataProcessing(MemcachedThreadUtil.java:59)
```

**Sample Program :**

*MemcacheUtil :*

```
public class MemcachedThreadUtil {

    /**
     * synchronized method
     */

    public synchronized void memcacheDataProcessing(String key, TermBean objUpdateTermBean) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Start");

        Object retrivedValue = retrieveFromMemCache(key);
        HashMap<String, TermBean> hmData = (HashMap<String, TermBean>) retrivedValue;

        hmData.put(key, objUpdateTermBean); // Data update

        addToMemCache(key, hmData);

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " End");
    }

    private Object retrieveFromMemCache(String key) {
        // MemCachedManager.getMcc().get(sKey);
    }

    private void addToMemCache(String key, HashMap<String, TermBean> hmData) {
        // MemCachedManager.getMcc().set(sKey, obj);
    }
}
```

*Runnable Thread :*

```
    public class SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String key;
    private TermBean objTermBean;
    private MemcachedThreadUtil memcacheThreadUtil;

    public SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable(String key, TermBean data, MemcachedThreadUtil memcacheThreadUtil) {
        this.key = key;
        this.objTermBean = data;
        this.memcacheThreadUtil = memcacheThreadUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            this.memcacheThreadUtil.memcacheDataProcessing(this.key, this.objTermBean);

        } catch (Exception iex) {
            System.out.println("Exception in thread: " + iex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

*Main method :*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MemcachedThreadUtil memcachedThreadUtil = new MemcachedThreadUtil();

    for (int threadCount = 0; threadCount < 10; threadCount++) {
        String key = ..//Get key 
        TermBean objTermBean = ..// get value
        SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable runnable = new SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable(key, objTermBean, memcachedThreadUtil);
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable, "Thread"+threadCount);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

**Memcached version** is - 1.4.17 { https://danga.com/ or http://memcached.org)

It seems that there is some issue inside the Memcached library where concurrency thing not handled or it might be simply HashMap iterator issue.

Could you please advise whether multithreading is creating this exception or it general issue with HashMap.

*Note :* I thought that synchronized method is creating problem so I changed concurrent threading implementation using ReentrantReadWriteLock concept but facing same issue.

How to solve this issue - any suggestion please.

**Edit : Added MemCachedManager code**

```
public class MemCachedManager {

protected static MemCachedClient mcc = null;

static {
    init();
}

public static void init() {

    String[] servers = new String[Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_SERVERS_COUNT", "cacheconfig"))];
    StringTokenizer stServers = new StringTokenizer(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_SERVERS_COMMA_SEPERATED", "cacheconfig"), ",");
    int iServersCnt = 0;
    while (null != stServers && stServers.hasMoreTokens()) {
        servers[iServersCnt] = stServers.nextToken();
        iServersCnt++;
    }

    Integer[] weights = new Integer[Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_SERVERS_COUNT", "cacheconfig"))];
    StringTokenizer stWeightage = new StringTokenizer(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_SERVERS_MEMORY_COMMA_SEPERATED", "cacheconfig"), ",");
    int iServersWeightageCnt = 0;
    while (null != stWeightage && stWeightage.hasMoreTokens()) {
        weights[iServersWeightageCnt] = Integer.valueOf(stWeightage.nextToken());
        iServersWeightageCnt++;
    }

    String sPoolName = LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_POOL_NAME", "cacheconfig");
    SockIOPool pool = SockIOPool.getInstance(sPoolName);

    pool.setServers(servers);
    pool.setWeights(weights);

    pool.setInitConn(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_INIT_CONN", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setMinConn(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_MIN_CONN", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setMaxConn(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_MAX_CONN", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_MAX_IDLE", "cacheconfig"))); // 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6  == 6 hrs

    pool.setMaintSleep(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_MAINTAIN_THREAD_SLEEP", "cacheconfig")));

    pool.setNagle(Boolean.parseBoolean(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_NAGLE_ENABLE_FLAG", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setSocketTO(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setSocketConnectTO(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setFailover(Boolean.parseBoolean(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_FAILOVER_ENABLE_FLAG", "cacheconfig")));
    pool.setAliveCheck(Boolean.parseBoolean(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("POOL_ALIVE_CHECK_ENABLE_FLAG", "cacheconfig")));

    // initialize the connection pool
    pool.initialize();

    mcc = new MemCachedClient(sPoolName);
    mcc.setCompressEnable(Boolean.parseBoolean(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_COMPRESSION_ENABLE_FLAG", "cacheconfig")));
    mcc.setCompressThreshold(Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_COMPRESSION_THRESHOLD_SIZE", "cacheconfig")));  //64 * 1024  == 64 kb

    int iLogLevel = com.danga.MemCached.Logger.LEVEL_WARN;
    if (GenTools.isNumber(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_LOG_LEVEL", "cacheconfig"))) {
        iLogLevel = Integer.parseInt(LocaleUtil.loadPropertyFile("MEMCACHED_LOG_LEVEL", "cacheconfig"));
    }
    setLogLevel(iLogLevel);
}

public static MemCachedClient getMcc() {
    return mcc;
}

public static void setMcc(MemCachedClient mcc) {
    MemCachedManager.mcc = mcc;
}

public static void setLogLevel(int iLogLevel) {
    com.danga.MemCached.Logger.getLogger(MemCachedClient.class.getName()).setLevel(iLogLevel);
}

public static long getNormalCounter(String sTabName) {
    return getMcc().incr(sTabName);
}

public static String getPrefixCounter(String sTabName) {
    return sTabName.concat(String.valueOf(getMcc().incr(sTabName)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

}

Comment: please post source code of `MemCachedManager`

Comment: added MemCachedManager source code.

Comment: Can you post the TermBean code? Also the code you posted for MemcachedThreadUtil doesn't match the stack trace...

Comment: I have implemented BlockingQueue for above issue and still getting ConcurrentModificationException. It seems Memcached is not supporting the multithreading.

Comment: We're using memcached under huge concurrency levels... I suspect you issue originates from the code you didn't post - the code for the class you're serializing. You can either post it, so we can help, or put a break point where the exception occurs and figure out which map you're modifying while you serialize it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure but try to make memcacheDataProcessing method static synchronized to get a class level lock.

Comment: static synchronized statements obtain a lock on the Class object. Only one instance of class will created in the JVM when application will start and then lock on class will hamper performance.

Comment: synchronized static applied on memcacheDataProcessing method but no change in exception still getting same exception.

Comment: I think you are creating threads with multiple objects of `SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable ` sharing same resource `MemcachedThreadUtil ` and since they are different objects Synchronised will not work as they are working independently of separate stacks.  In this case, I think ,you need to have a class level lock on `SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable` so that no two threads simultaneously call your `MemcachedThreadUtil `. Use this
`static(SendNForgotMemcacheHelperRunnable.class){
this.memcacheThreadUtil.memcacheDataProcessing(this.key, this.objTermBean);
}`
I wish this helps.

Comment: please refer this link - http://crunchify.com/have-you-noticed-race-condition-in-java-multithreading-concurrency-example-how-to-deal-with-it/